# Problems while scrolling: scrollbar jumps randomly(?)

Tags: mouse, mouse-scroll, scrolling

I use ubuntu 14.04 on VirtualBox.

When I scroll vertically on a page the viewable area sometimes jumps to another part of the page. E.g. I scroll down on a website and the window jumps back to the top of the page. I experienced this using Firefox, Eclipse and the QtCreator (would probably also happen in other programms, if I use them).

What I noticed (this are just observed correlations, because of my limited knowledge of Linux I don't know if there is a causation):

- the viewable area jumps most of the time back to a point where I either clicked on the page last time or marked some text (don't know whether this is always the case, often I subconsciously click somewhere)
- It started around two days ago. At this time I also installed the CompizConfig Setting Manager and deactivated window-closing-animations and such. Reactivated the animations, but the scrolling problem stayed.

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem? Do you need anymore information? It's driving me nuts, especially while debugging.

Comment: Can't really edit my question, so I will add some comments this way:

1. The first observed correlation is probably wrong. Now I think it has nothing to do with clicking on the page.

2. It seems to be a problem with virtualbox. (A coworker has similar problems with the mouse wheel in virtualbox)